# jQuery Slider Won't Animate Inside These <div> Tags?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slider

I followed a tutorial online to build a slider, and got it to work nicely on it's own. However, when I take the code from my files and transfer them into the website I'd like to use them on, the slider doesn't work. It doesn't display the captions or anything like that.

**Here's the Javascript:**

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      

//Execute the slideShow, set 4 seconds for each images
slideShow(2000);

});

function slideShow(speed) {


    //append a LI item to the UL list for displaying caption
    $('ul.slideshow').append('<li id="slideshow-caption" class="caption"><div     class="slideshow-caption-container"><h3></h3><p></p></div></li>');

//Set the opacity of all images to 0
$('ul.slideshow li').css({opacity: 0.0});

//Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
$('ul.slideshow li:first').css({opacity: 1.0}).addClass('show');

//Get the caption of the first image from REL attribute and display it
$('#slideshow-caption h3').html($('ul.slideshow li.show').find('img').attr('title'));
$('#slideshow-caption p').html($('ul.slideshow li.show').find('img').attr('alt'));

//Display the caption
$('#slideshow-caption').css({opacity: 0.7, bottom:0});

//Call the gallery function to run the slideshow    
var timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);

//pause the slideshow on mouse over
$('ul.slideshow').hover(
    function () {
        clearInterval(timer);   
    },  
    function () {
        timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);         
    }
    );

}

function gallery() {


//if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
var current = ($('ul.slideshow li.show')?  $('ul.slideshow li.show') : $('#ul.slideshow li:first'));

//trying to avoid speed issue
if(current.queue('fx').length == 0) {

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption')? $('ul.slideshow li:first') :current.next()) : $('ul.slideshow li:first'));

    //Get next image caption
    var title = next.find('img').attr('title'); 
    var desc = next.find('img').attr('alt');    

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the caption first, and then set and display the caption
    $('#slideshow-caption').slideToggle(300, function () { 
        $('#slideshow-caption h3').html(title); 
        $('#slideshow-caption p').html(desc); 
        $('#slideshow-caption').slideToggle(500); 
    }); 

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000).removeClass('show');

    }

}
</script>
```

**Here's the HTML Code**

```
<div id="masthead-wrapper">
    <div id="masthead"></div>
</div>
<div id="navbar-wrapper">
<div id="navbar-left"></div>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">CATERING</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">WHOLESALE</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="navbar-right"></div><!-- END NAVIGATION -->
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">
            <!-- SLIDER -->
            <div id="slider-container">

            <ul class="slideshow">
                <li class="show"><a href="#"><img src="slide-1.jpg" width="618" height="246" title="Delicious Desserts" alt="something funny." /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="slide-2.jpg" width="618" height="246" title="Slide 2" alt="Something funny." /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="slide-3.jpg" width="618" height="246" title="Slide 3" alt="Something funny." /></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- END SLIDER -->
        </div><!-- END CONTENT -->
    </div><!-- END MAIN -->
</div><!-- END MAIN WRAPPER -->

<div id="footerwrapper">
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**Lastly, The CSS**

```
ul.slideshow {
list-style:none; 
width:618px;
height:246px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;

}   

ul.slideshow li {
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}

ul.slideshow li.show {
z-index:500;    
}

ul img {
border:none;    
}

#slideshow-caption {
width:300px;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0; 
color:#fff;
background:#000;
z-index:500;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
}

#slideshow-caption .slideshow-caption-container {
padding:5px 10px;   
z-index:1000;   
}

#slideshow-caption h3 {
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 10px;
padding:0;  
font-size:18px;
}

#slideshow-caption p {
margin:5px 0 0 0;
padding:0;
}
```

I feel like there's a really simply solution to the problem that I'm just not getting. Can anyone help me out here? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check for any errors on the console? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you give the link of that tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was this offending line:

```
timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);
```

It should be:

```
timer = setInterval(gallery,speed);
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action (without pics):

http://jsfiddle.net/cFbAd/2/

This is because [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) requires a reference to a function, not a string.

Comment: Not quite, passing `gallery()` to the `setInterval` method will pass-in the `return` of the `gallery()` function, if you want to pass a reference to the function so it will run at the interval, just omit the parenthesis: `timer = setInterval(gallery,speed);`. The main difference is that `gallery()` is immediately invoked and `gallery` is a reference that will be invoked at the interval.

Comment: @Jasper, thanks for catching that! Updated to reflect your suggestion.